# Java.text.NumberFormat parse method not parsing properly for the locale

Tags: java, junit

I have some code which formats a given number.  The code formats based on a set locale in the users profile.  If the user enters in a "broken" number such as 551$44 only the 551 is returned and the 44 is forgotten.  I need a way for the $ to be pulled out and the 55144 to be shown.

```
static double formatNumber(String number, Locale locale, char decimalSeparator) throws ParseException {
    double rtn = 0.0;
    if (decimalSeparator == ',') {
        if (number.indexOf(decimalSeparator) == -1) {
            rtn = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en")).parse(number).doubleValue();
        } else {
            rtn = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale).parse(number).doubleValue();
        }
    } else {
        if (number.indexOf(decimalSeparator) == -1) {
            rtn = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("fr")).parse(number).doubleValue();
        } else {
            rtn = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale).parse(number).doubleValue();
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

That code is the formatter that checks to see what the decimalSeparator is for the locale and compares it to a comma.  Then it checks to see the index of the decimalSeparator then changes the locale to use en.  I have written a test that checks multiple "broken" numbers and it fails when it comes to "1.478,451,0" because it pulls out the comma and just stops instead of adding on the 4510.

```
@Test
public void testFormatBrokenNumbersENCA() throws ParseException {
    Locale locale = new Locale("en_CA");
    Double[] parsedNumbers = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.478451, 1.1,
            1.1, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 3.141592653589793, (double) 111555999 };
    String[] numbers = { "0     ", "0.,,,,,0", "0,,,,,0", "1,,", "1.m0",
            "1.478,451,0", "1.1.1", "1,1,1", "-1-", "-1.0-", "-1,0+-",
            "3.141592$65,35%89793", "111 555 999" };
    String[] failures = { "0     was passed in", "0.,,,,,0 was passed in",
            "0,,,,,0 was passed in", "1,, was passed in",
            "1.m0 was passed in", "1.478,451,0 was passed in",
            "1.1.1 was passed in", "1,1,1 was passed in",
            "-1- was passed in", "-1.0- was passed in",
            "-1,0-+ was passed in", "3.141592$65,35%89793 was passed in",
            "111 555 999 was passed in" };

    for (int i = 0; i < parsedNumbers.length; i++) {
        assertEquals(failures[i], parsedNumbers[i],
                Validation.getNumber(numbers[i], locale));
    }

}
```

Is there any possible way to parse with the locale the user decides and keep all numbers no matter what the user types?

Comment: Where is the user entering the number? A `JTextField`, a file, ...? If it is a `JTextfield`, you could add a `Document` to it to filter out invalid characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the parse position reached the end. If not delete the char at the parse position. Use parse with explicit [ParsePosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29)

```
for (;;) {
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    nf.parse(number, pos);
    if (pos.getErrorIndex() != -1) { // In fact for the exception catch.
        break;
    }
    int i = pos.getIndex();
    if (i == number.length()) { // Did all.
        break;
    }
    number = number.substring(0, i) + number.substring(i + 1);
}
```